# Substitute for $DOCUMENT_ROOT without register_globals?

Tags: php, document-root, register-globals

I have a website (hand-coded HTML/CSS/PHP) with many hundreds of pages, each with multiple references to `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` - for example:

```
<?php include("$DOCUMENT_ROOT/home/index.html"); ?>
```

Under PHP 5 that worked fine, but `register_globals` has been deprecated and removed from PHP 7, so it doesn't work anymore.

I don't want to hard-code the path to the file because my testing server and live server use different paths to the files - for example:

Testing server: `/home4/testing/public_html/home/index.html`

Live server:    `/home4/live/public_html/home/index.html`

(Plus, just on general principles, it seems like a bad idea to hard-code paths needlessly.)

I gather that, syntactically, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` or `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` can replace `$DOCUMENT_ROOT`.

I tried a simple search-and-replace on my source HTML:

```
<?php include("$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]/home/index.html"); ?>
```

and

```
<?php include("$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/home/index.html"); ?>
```

Both don't work - I get ERROR 500.

The first one pretty obviously has a problem with string quoting (too many `"` in the wrong places).

But the second one doesn't work either (also ERROR 500).

How can I get my site working on PHP 7?

Is there something I can put in `.htaccess` or `php.ini` to define `$DOCUMENT_ROOT`?

Or is there a different syntax that'll work for `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`?

Or is there a better solution?

My main goal is to get it working again ASAP (it's a company website, and it's down because Hostgator has pulled PHP 5 support for security reasons), without creating worse problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. It's ugly, but it seems to work.

I did a brute-force replacement of:

```
"$DOCUMENT_ROOT
```

with:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."
```

...across the entire website.

It's ugly, but it's working. Suggestions for improvement are welcome.

Comment: You could also use `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]` if all instances are within double-quoted strings, eg `"$DOCUMENT_ROOT/home/index.html"` becomes `"$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/home/index.html"`

Comment: Another method is to use the `auto-prepend-file`, and add `extract($_SERVER);` in that auto prepend file. It would be a maintenance nightmare later on, but is definitely doable https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file